# Why use the PayPal API?

Tags: paypal

As a developer, I want to know what are the advantages of using PayPal API?

I know there are a ton of APIs out there to use, but if I will use the PayPal API specifically, what are the benefits of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically people use the PayPal API if they have a business that wants to process payments via PayPal. It's not a developer question.

Your question becomes, really, what are the advantages of processing payments with PayPal? And there may be interesting answers to that question but this isn't the place.

---

Edit:

Ok I did think of something that can be added from a developer and solutioning perspective

[Look at the demo code here](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client)

See how easy that is. Now actually click one of the buttons. See how the window emerges, and how quick and natural the payment experience is for the user--with the originating website staying loaded in the background.

Think also about the security of this payment experience. All the buyer's financial instruments are saved and stored at PayPal; nothing is shared with the (potentially new/unfamiliar) ecommerce site they are paying, whereas PayPal is a relatively trusted name by many millions of buyers.

So, TL;DR : it's very easy, it's very quick (no retyping things) and secure, and people trust it enough to actually send you money and hope you will deliver on the new product/service you are offering